# Getting erro in Dropdown control selectedindexchanged event?

Tags: asp.net

in my web application when i select a dropdown control which is giving error like.
Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.   This is my code...

```
    try
    {             
        ddlState.Items.Clear();
        ddlState.Enabled = true;
        ListItem li1 = new ListItem();
        li1.Value = "0";
        li1.Text = "Select State";
        ddlState.Items.Add(li1);
        clsStates.Countryid = int.Parse(ddlCountry.SelectedValue.ToString());
        DataSet ds = clsStates.selectStateBl();
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            li1 = new ListItem();
            li1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["statename"].ToString();
            li1.Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["stateid"].ToString();
            ddlState.DataTextField = "statename";
            ddlState.DataValueField = "stateid";
            ddlState.Items.Add(li1);
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

this is binding the countries code...

```
     try
    {

        ListItem li = new ListItem();

        DataSet ds = clsCountrys.selectCountryB();

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            li = new ListItem();
            li.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["countryname"].ToString();
            li.Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["countryid"].ToString();
            if (li.Value == Session["usercountry"].ToString())
                li.Selected = true;
            ddlCountry.DataTextField = "countryname";
            ddlCountry.DataValueField = "countryid";
            ddlCountry.Items.Add(li);
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

and this is state binding to dropdown control..

```
     try
    {
        ddlState.Items.Clear();
        ddlState.Enabled = true;
        ddlState.ClearSelection();
        ListItem li1 = new ListItem();
        li1.Value = "0";
        li1.Text = "Select State";
        ddlState.Items.Add(li1);
        clsStates.Countryid = int.Parse(ddlCountry.SelectedValue.ToString());
        DataSet ds = clsStates.selectStateBl();
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            li1 = new ListItem();
            li1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["statename"].ToString();
            li1.Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["stateid"].ToString();
            if (Session["userstate"].ToString() == li1.Value)
                li1.Selected = true;
            ddlState.DataTextField = "statename";
            ddlState.DataValueField = "stateid";
            ddlState.Items.Add(li1);
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

Comment: check the edited answer will do work for you

Comment: check this block of the code    //code updated by pranay rana

Comment: no pranay i place the code but it is giving same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `ddlState.ClearSelection()` method to clear default selection.

Check this post : [ASP.NET Tips: DropDownList.ClearSelection() to avoid "Cannot have multiple items selected in DropDownList"](http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2008/08/23/124652.aspx)

**EDIT**

```
  try
    {
        ddlState.ClearSelection();
        ddlState.Items.Clear();
        ddlState.Enabled = true;

        ListItem li1 = new ListItem();
        li1.Value = "0";
        li1.Text = "Select State";
        ddlState.Items.Add(li1);
        clsStates.Countryid = int.Parse(ddlCountry.SelectedValue.ToString());
        DataSet ds = clsStates.selectStateBl();
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            li1 = new ListItem();
            li1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["statename"].ToString();
            li1.Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["stateid"].ToString();

            ddlState.DataTextField = "statename";
            ddlState.DataValueField = "stateid";
            ddlState.Items.Add(li1);

        }

          //code updated by pranay rana
           ddlState.ClearSelection();
              ListItem li = ddlState.Items.FindByValue(Session["userstate"].ToString());
                if (li != null)
                {
                    li.Selected = true;
                }
           //code updated by pranay rana
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

Comment: @pranay Rana i write u r code  in the event but it is not working

Comment: @Surya sasidhar : - just write this in the function where are you binding value to dropdownlist i.e after binding data

Comment: @prany Rana actually i have 2 drop down button one for binding the countryies and when i select country in one dropdown i am binding the state of that country i have two dropdown controls.

Comment: just writ above code when you bind the values for the both of dropdown  box will work for you

Comment: Check the posted link will help you

Comment: ya i check that one i just edited my question plese check out once thank you for reply

Comment: @Surya sasidhar :- just try to put this line ddlState.ClearSelection(); before you selecting value programmaticaly

Comment: Pranay rana can u tell me where exactly in event or in binding the data

Comment: @Surya sasidhar : just copy and paste code given by me and see its working or not i.e edit section code to bind state dropdown box